# Woocommerce wc-page-functions.php

Tags: wordpress, navigation, woocommerce

The file is located at:

```
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-page-functions.php
```

and can be viewed here:
https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-page-functions.php

There's a function namaed `wc_nav_menu_item_classes` which apparently is used to assign `'current-menu-item'` & `'current_page_item'` classes to menu items.

In my navigation menu, I have the main SHOP link which shows all categories and their links to the products. When I choose a category/subcategory or a single product it doesn't highlight the main SHOP link in the menu. I was able to fix this by adding 2 lines of code to the mentioned function:

```
// Set active state if this is the shop page link
        } elseif ( is_shop() && $shop_page == $menu_item->object_id

            /* MY EDIT */   
         || (is_singular( 'product' ) && $shop_page == $menu_item->object_id)
         || (is_archive( 'product' ) && $shop_page == $menu_item->object_id)
            /* END MY EDIT */

         ) {
            $menu_items[ $key ]->current = true;
            $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
            $classes[] = 'current_page_item';

        // Set parent state if this is a product page
        }
```

now when I add a link of a category to the main navigation menu, it doesn't highlight the menu item when viewing subcategories or single products related to that category. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can't you just style the `.current_page_parent` class?

Comment: @helgatheviking actually I styled the .current-product_cat-ancestor class and it worked. But functions.php is less work. Cuz then if you wanted to change the color of the highlighted link, you'll change it only in 1 place.

Comment: You can just put `.current_page_parent, .current-menu-item { color: red; } ` on the same line.